# SImple inserts into our mysql8 installation are very slow

Tags: mysql

We migrated several development databases to mysql8 a couple months ago and it was onlyin running large imports/sql scripts that we realized how slow our inserts are.
As an example I created a table as follows and inserted 1000 records,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ciiu_test2` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codbut` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ciiu` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt` float(14,2) DEFAULT NULL
)
delete from ciiu_test2;
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(3)) into @ctime;
INSERT INTO `ciiu_test2` (`id`, `codbut`, `ciiu`,dt) VALUES (1, '1', '1',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(3))-@ctime);
INSERT INTO `ciiu_test2` (`id`, `codbut`, `ciiu`,dt) VALUES (2, '2', '2',UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(3))-@ctime);
```

etc...
With autocommit on, it took 45 seconds to insert 1000 records, with autocommit off, putting everything under one transaction, it took around .6 seconds

Now, I have read about logging and I've turned off logging that might cause a problem. WE don't have replication running. In fact, I have a mysql8 running off docker with the same configuration and no issue.
Here is the configuration for the mysql8 server and the one for docker

| Variable_name | 167value | 51_8value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| auto_generate_certs | ON | ON |
| auto_increment_increment | 1 | 1 |
| auto_increment_offset | 1 | 1 |
| autocommit | ON | ON |
| automatic_sp_privileges | ON | ON |
| avoid_temporal_upgrade | OFF | OFF |
| back_log | 151 | 151 |
| basedir | /usr/ | /usr/ |
| big_tables | OFF | OFF |
| bind_address | * | * |
| binlog_cache_size | 32768 | 32768 |
| binlog_checksum | CRC32 | CRC32 |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates | OFF | OFF |
| binlog_error_action | ABORT_SERVER | ABORT_SERVER |
| binlog_format | ROW | ROW |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_delay | 0 | 0 |
| binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count | 0 | 0 |
| binlog_gtid_simple_recovery | ON | ON |
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time | 0 | 0 |
| binlog_order_commits | ON | ON |
| binlog_row_image | FULL | FULL |
| binlog_rows_query_log_events | OFF | OFF |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size | 32768 | 32768 |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size | 25000 | 25000 |
| binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking | COMMIT_ORDER | COMMIT_ORDER |
| block_encryption_mode | aes-128-ecb | aes-128-ecb |
| bulk_insert_buffer_size | 8388608 | 8388608 |
| character_sets_dir | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
| check_proxy_users | OFF | OFF |
| concurrent_insert | AUTO | AUTO |
| connect_timeout | 10 | 10 |
| core_file | OFF | OFF |
| datadir | /var/lib/mysql/ | /var/lib/mysql/ |
| date_format | not_defined | not_defined |
| datetime_format | not_defined | not_defined |
| default_authentication_plugin | mysql_native_password | caching_sha2_password |
| default_password_lifetime | 0 | 0 |
| default_storage_engine | InnoDB | InnoDB |
| default_tmp_storage_engine | InnoDB | InnoDB |
| default_week_format | 0 | 0 |
| delay_key_write | ON | ON |
| delayed_insert_limit | 100 | 100 |
| delayed_insert_timeout | 300 | 300 |
| delayed_queue_size | 1000 | 1000 |
| disabled_storage_engines |  |  |
| disconnect_on_expired_password | ON | ON |
| div_precision_increment | 4 | 4 |
| end_markers_in_json | OFF | OFF |
| enforce_gtid_consistency | OFF | OFF |
| eq_range_index_dive_limit | 200 | 200 |
| error_count | 0 | 0 |
| event_scheduler | ON | ON |
| expire_logs_days | 0 | 0 |
| explicit_defaults_for_timestamp | ON | ON |
| external_user |  |  |
| flush | OFF | OFF |
| flush_time | 0 | 0 |
| foreign_key_checks | ON | ON |
| ft_boolean_syntax | + -><()~*:""&| | + -><()~*:""&| |
| ft_max_word_len | 84 | 84 |
| ft_min_word_len | 4 | 4 |
| ft_query_expansion_limit | 20 | 20 |
| ft_stopword_file | (built-in) | (built-in) |
| general_log | OFF | OFF |
| general_log_file | /var/lib/mysql/ns515408.log | /var/lib/mysql/093b8c5ba5be.log |
| group_concat_max_len | 1024 | 1024 |
| gtid_executed_compression_period | 1000 | 1000 |
| gtid_mode | OFF | OFF |
| gtid_next | AUTOMATIC | AUTOMATIC |
| gtid_owned |  |  |
| gtid_purged |  |  |
| have_compress | YES | YES |
| have_crypt | not_defined | not_defined |
| have_dynamic_loading | YES | YES |
| have_geometry | YES | YES |
| have_openssl | YES | YES |
| have_profiling | YES | YES |
| have_query_cache | NO | NO |
| have_rtree_keys | YES | YES |
| have_ssl | YES | YES |
| have_statement_timeout | YES | YES |
| have_symlink | DISABLED | DISABLED |
| host_cache_size | 279 | 279 |
| hostname | ns515408.ip-167-114-174.net | 093b8c5ba5be |
| identity | 0 | 0 |
| ignore_builtin_innodb | not_defined | not_defined |
| ignore_db_dirs | not_defined | not_defined |
| init_connect |  |  |
| init_file |  |  |
| init_slave |  |  |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing | ON | ON |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm | 10 | 10 |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index | ON | ON |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts | 8 | 8 |
| innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay | 150000 | 150000 |
| innodb_api_bk_commit_interval | 5 | 5 |
| innodb_api_disable_rowlock | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_api_enable_mdl | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_api_trx_level | 0 | 0 |
| innodb_autoextend_increment | 64 | 64 |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode | 2 | 2 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size | 134217728 | 134217728 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown | ON | ON |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct | 25 | 25 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename | ib_buffer_pool | ib_buffer_pool |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances | 1 | 1 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup | ON | ON |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 134217728 | 134217728 |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size | 25 | 25 |
| innodb_change_buffering | all | all |
| innodb_checksum_algorithm | crc32 | crc32 |
| innodb_checksums | not_defined | not_defined |
| innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_commit_concurrency | 0 | 0 |
| innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct | 5 | 5 |
| innodb_compression_level | 6 | 6 |
| innodb_compression_pad_pct_max | 50 | 50 |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets | 5000 | 5000 |
| innodb_data_file_path | ibdata1:12M:autoextend | ibdata1:12M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir |  |  |
| innodb_deadlock_detect | ON | ON |
| innodb_default_row_format | dynamic | dynamic |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_doublewrite | ON | ON |
| innodb_fast_shutdown | 1 | 1 |
| innodb_file_format | not_defined | not_defined |
| innodb_file_format_check | not_defined | not_defined |
| innodb_file_format_max | not_defined | not_defined |
| innodb_file_per_table | ON | ON |
| innodb_fill_factor | 100 | 100 |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1 | 1 |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit | 1 | 1 |
| innodb_flush_method | fsync | fsync |
| innodb_flush_neighbors | 0 | 0 |
| innodb_flush_sync | ON | ON |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops | 30 | 30 |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_force_recovery | 0 | 0 |
| innodb_ft_aux_table |  |  |
| innodb_ft_cache_size | 8000000 | 8000000 |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword | ON | ON |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size | 84 | 84 |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size | 3 | 3 |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize | 2000 | 2000 |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit | 2000000000 | 2000000000 |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table |  |  |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree | 2 | 2 |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size | 640000000 | 640000000 |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table |  |  |
| innodb_io_capacity | 200 | 200 |
| innodb_io_capacity_max | 2000 | 2000 |
| innodb_large_prefix | not_defined | not_defined |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 50 | 50 |
| innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog | not_defined | not_defined |
| innodb_log_buffer_size | 16777216 | 16777216 |
| innodb_log_checksums | ON | ON |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages | ON | ON |
| innodb_log_file_size | 50331648 | 50331648 |
| innodb_log_files_in_group | 2 | 2 |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir | ./ | ./ |
| innodb_log_write_ahead_size | 8192 | 8192 |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth | 1024 | 1024 |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct | 90 | 90 |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm | 10 | 10 |
| innodb_max_purge_lag | 0 | 0 |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay | 0 | 0 |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size | 1073741824 | 1073741824 |
| innodb_monitor_disable |  |  |
| innodb_monitor_enable |  |  |
| innodb_monitor_reset |  |  |
| innodb_monitor_reset_all |  |  |
| innodb_numa_interleave | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct | 37 | 37 |
| innodb_old_blocks_time | 1000 | 1000 |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size | 134217728 | 134217728 |
| innodb_open_files | 4000 | 4000 |
| innodb_optimize_fulltext_only | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_page_cleaners | 1 | 1 |
| innodb_page_size | 16384 | 16384 |
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_purge_batch_size | 300 | 300 |
| innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency | 128 | 128 |
| innodb_purge_threads | 4 | 4 |
| innodb_random_read_ahead | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold | 56 | 56 |
| innodb_read_io_threads | 4 | 4 |
| innodb_read_only | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_replication_delay | 0 | 0 |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_rollback_segments | 128 | 128 |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size | 1048576 | 1048576 |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay | 6 | 6 |
| innodb_stats_auto_recalc | ON | ON |
| innodb_stats_include_delete_marked | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_stats_method | nulls_equal | nulls_equal |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_stats_persistent | ON | ON |
| innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages | 20 | 20 |
| innodb_stats_sample_pages | not_defined | not_defined |
| innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages | 8 | 8 |
| innodb_status_output | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_status_output_locks | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_strict_mode | ON | ON |
| innodb_support_xa | not_defined | not_defined |
| innodb_sync_array_size | 1 | 1 |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops | 30 | 30 |
| innodb_table_locks | ON | ON |
| innodb_temp_data_file_path | ibtmp1:12M:autoextend | ibtmp1:12M:autoextend |
| innodb_thread_concurrency | 0 | 0 |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay | 10000 | 10000 |
| innodb_tmpdir |  |  |
| innodb_undo_directory | ./ | ./ |
| innodb_undo_log_truncate | ON | ON |
| innodb_undo_logs | not_defined | not_defined |
| innodb_undo_tablespaces | 2 | 2 |
| innodb_use_native_aio | ON | ON |
| innodb_version | 8.0.21 | 8.0.22 |
| innodb_write_io_threads | 4 | 4 |
| insert_id | 0 | 0 |
| interactive_timeout | 28800 | 28800 |
| internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine | not_defined | not_defined |
| join_buffer_size | 262144 | 262144 |
| keep_files_on_create | OFF | OFF |
| key_buffer_size | 8388608 | 8388608 |
| key_cache_age_threshold | 300 | 300 |
| key_cache_block_size | 1024 | 1024 |
| key_cache_division_limit | 100 | 100 |
| keyring_operations | ON | ON |
| large_files_support | ON | ON |
| large_page_size | 0 | 0 |
| large_pages | OFF | OFF |
| last_insert_id | 0 | 0 |
| lc_messages | en_US | en_US |
| lc_messages_dir | /usr/share/mysql/ | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/ |
| lc_time_names | en_US | en_US |
| license | GPL | GPL |
| local_infile | OFF | OFF |
| lock_wait_timeout | 31536000 | 31536000 |
| locked_in_memory | OFF | OFF |
| log_bin | ON | ON |
| log_bin_basename | /var/lib/mysql/binlog | /var/lib/mysql/binlog |
| log_bin_index | /var/lib/mysql/binlog.index | /var/lib/mysql/binlog.index |
| log_bin_trust_function_creators | OFF | OFF |
| log_bin_use_v1_row_events | OFF | OFF |
| log_builtin_as_identified_by_password | not_defined | not_defined |
| log_error | /var/log/mysql/mysqld.log | stderr |
| log_error_verbosity | 2 | 2 |
| log_output | FILE | FILE |
| log_queries_not_using_indexes | OFF | OFF |
| log_slave_updates | ON | ON |
| log_slow_admin_statements | OFF | OFF |
| log_slow_slave_statements | OFF | OFF |
| log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog | ON | ON |
| log_syslog | not_defined | not_defined |
| log_syslog_facility | not_defined | not_defined |
| log_syslog_include_pid | not_defined | not_defined |
| log_syslog_tag | not_defined | not_defined |
| log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes | 0 | 0 |
| log_timestamps | UTC | UTC |
| log_warnings | not_defined | not_defined |
| long_query_time | 10 | 10 |
| max_allowed_packet | 67108864 | 67108864 |
| max_binlog_cache_size | 1.84467E+19 | 1.84467E+19 |
| max_binlog_size | 1073741824 | 1073741824 |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size | 1.84467E+19 | 1.84467E+19 |
| max_connect_errors | 100 | 100 |
| max_connections | 151 | 151 |
| max_delayed_threads | 20 | 20 |
| max_digest_length | 1024 | 1024 |
| max_error_count | 1024 | 1024 |
| max_execution_time | 0 | 0 |
| max_heap_table_size | 16777216 | 16777216 |
| max_insert_delayed_threads | 20 | 20 |
| max_join_size | 1.84467E+19 | 1.84467E+19 |
| max_length_for_sort_data | 4096 | 4096 |
| max_points_in_geometry | 65536 | 65536 |
| max_prepared_stmt_count | 16382 | 16382 |
| max_relay_log_size | 0 | 0 |
| max_seeks_for_key | 1.84467E+19 | 1.84467E+19 |
| max_sort_length | 1024 | 1024 |
| max_sp_recursion_depth | 0 | 0 |
| max_tmp_tables | not_defined | not_defined |
| max_user_connections | 0 | 0 |
| max_write_lock_count | 1.84467E+19 | 1.84467E+19 |
| metadata_locks_cache_size | not_defined | not_defined |
| metadata_locks_hash_instances | not_defined | not_defined |
| min_examined_row_limit | 0 | 0 |
| multi_range_count | not_defined | not_defined |
| myisam_data_pointer_size | 6 | 6 |
| myisam_max_sort_file_size | 9.22337E+18 | 9.22337E+18 |
| myisam_mmap_size | 1.84467E+19 | 1.84467E+19 |
| myisam_recover_options | OFF | OFF |
| myisam_repair_threads | 1 | 1 |
| myisam_sort_buffer_size | 8388608 | 8388608 |
| myisam_stats_method | nulls_unequal | nulls_unequal |
| myisam_use_mmap | OFF | OFF |
| mysql_native_password_proxy_users | OFF | OFF |
| net_buffer_length | 16384 | 16384 |
| net_read_timeout | 30 | 30 |
| net_retry_count | 10 | 10 |
| net_write_timeout | 60 | 60 |
| new | OFF | OFF |
| open_files_limit | 10000 | 1048576 |
| optimizer_prune_level | 1 | 1 |
| optimizer_search_depth | 62 | 62 |
| optimizer_switch | index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on,use_invisible_indexes=off,skip_scan=on,hash_join=on,subquery_to_derived=off,prefer_ordering_index=on | index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,duplicateweedout=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,condition_fanout_filter=on,derived_merge=on,use_invisible_indexes=off,skip_scan=on,hash_join=on,subquery_to_derived=off,prefer_ordering_index=on,hypergraph_optimizer=off,derived_condition_pushdown=on |
| optimizer_trace | enabled=off,one_line=off | enabled=off,one_line=off |
| optimizer_trace_features | greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on | greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on |
| optimizer_trace_limit | 1 | 1 |
| optimizer_trace_max_mem_size | 1048576 | 1048576 |
| optimizer_trace_offset | -1 | -1 |
| parser_max_mem_size | 1.84467E+19 | 1.84467E+19 |
| performance_schema | ON | ON |
| performance_schema_accounts_size | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_digests_size | 10000 | 10000 |
| performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size | 10000 | 10000 |
| performance_schema_events_stages_history_size | 10 | 10 |
| performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size | 10000 | 10000 |
| performance_schema_events_statements_history_size | 10 | 10 |
| performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size | 10000 | 10000 |
| performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size | 10 | 10 |
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size | 10000 | 10000 |
| performance_schema_events_waits_history_size | 10 | 10 |
| performance_schema_hosts_size | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_cond_classes | 100 | 100 |
| performance_schema_max_cond_instances | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_digest_length | 1024 | 1024 |
| performance_schema_max_file_classes | 80 | 80 |
| performance_schema_max_file_handles | 32768 | 32768 |
| performance_schema_max_file_instances | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_index_stat | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_memory_classes | 450 | 450 |
| performance_schema_max_metadata_locks | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_mutex_classes | 300 | 300 |
| performance_schema_max_mutex_instances | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_program_instances | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes | 60 | 60 |
| performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_socket_classes | 10 | 10 |
| performance_schema_max_socket_instances | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_sql_text_length | 1024 | 1024 |
| performance_schema_max_stage_classes | 175 | 175 |
| performance_schema_max_statement_classes | 218 | 218 |
| performance_schema_max_statement_stack | 10 | 10 |
| performance_schema_max_table_handles | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_table_instances | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_max_thread_classes | 100 | 100 |
| performance_schema_max_thread_instances | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size | 512 | 512 |
| performance_schema_setup_actors_size | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_setup_objects_size | -1 | -1 |
| performance_schema_users_size | -1 | -1 |
| port | 3306 | 3306 |
| preload_buffer_size | 32768 | 32768 |
| profiling | ON | ON |
| profiling_history_size | 15 | 15 |
| protocol_version | 10 | 10 |
| proxy_user |  |  |
| pseudo_slave_mode | OFF | OFF |
| pseudo_thread_id | 13855 | 13 |
| query_alloc_block_size | 8192 | 8192 |
| query_cache_limit | not_defined | not_defined |
| query_cache_min_res_unit | not_defined | not_defined |
| query_cache_size | not_defined | not_defined |
| query_cache_type | not_defined | not_defined |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | not_defined | not_defined |
| query_prealloc_size | 8192 | 8192 |
| rand_seed1 | 0 | 0 |
| rand_seed2 | 0 | 0 |
| range_alloc_block_size | 4096 | 4096 |
| range_optimizer_max_mem_size | 8388608 | 8388608 |
| rbr_exec_mode | STRICT | STRICT |
| read_buffer_size | 131072 | 131072 |
| read_only | OFF | OFF |
| read_rnd_buffer_size | 262144 | 262144 |
| relay_log | ns515408-relay-bin | 093b8c5ba5be-relay-bin |
| relay_log_basename | /var/lib/mysql/ns515408-relay-bin | /var/lib/mysql/093b8c5ba5be-relay-bin |
| relay_log_index | /var/lib/mysql/ns515408-relay-bin.index | /var/lib/mysql/093b8c5ba5be-relay-bin.index |
| relay_log_info_file | relay-log.info | relay-log.info |
| relay_log_info_repository | TABLE | TABLE |
| relay_log_purge | ON | ON |
| relay_log_recovery | OFF | OFF |
| relay_log_space_limit | 0 | 0 |
| replication_optimize_for_static_plugin_config | not_defined | not_defined |
| replication_sender_observe_commit_only | not_defined | not_defined |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout | 31536000 | 31536000 |
| secure_auth | not_defined | not_defined |
| secure_file_priv | /var/lib/mysql-files/ | NULL |
| server_id | 1 | 1 |
| server_id_bits | 32 | 32 |
| server_uuid | 96c5e0e3-73bc-11eb-873b-a4bf011f053a | c16243c8-1f86-11eb-ab83-0242ac110002 |
| session_track_gtids | OFF | OFF |
| session_track_schema | ON | ON |
| session_track_state_change | OFF | OFF |
| session_track_system_variables | time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection | time_zone,autocommit,character_set_client,character_set_results,character_set_connection |
| session_track_transaction_info | OFF | OFF |
| sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys | ON | ON |
| sha256_password_private_key_path | private_key.pem | private_key.pem |
| sha256_password_proxy_users | OFF | OFF |
| sha256_password_public_key_path | public_key.pem | public_key.pem |
| show_compatibility_56 | not_defined | not_defined |
| show_create_table_verbosity | OFF | OFF |
| show_old_temporals | OFF | OFF |
| skip_external_locking | ON | ON |
| skip_name_resolve | OFF | ON |
| skip_networking | OFF | OFF |
| skip_show_database | OFF | OFF |
| slave_allow_batching | OFF | OFF |
| slave_checkpoint_group | 512 | 512 |
| slave_checkpoint_period | 300 | 300 |
| slave_compressed_protocol | OFF | OFF |
| slave_exec_mode | STRICT | STRICT |
| slave_load_tmpdir | /var/tmp | /tmp |
| slave_max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 | 1073741824 |
| slave_net_timeout | 60 | 60 |
| slave_parallel_type | DATABASE | DATABASE |
| slave_parallel_workers | 0 | 0 |
| slave_pending_jobs_size_max | 134217728 | 134217728 |
| slave_preserve_commit_order | OFF | OFF |
| slave_rows_search_algorithms | INDEX_SCAN,HASH_SCAN | INDEX_SCAN,HASH_SCAN |
| slave_skip_errors | OFF | OFF |
| slave_sql_verify_checksum | ON | ON |
| slave_transaction_retries | 10 | 10 |
| slave_type_conversions |  |  |
| slow_launch_time | 2 | 2 |
| slow_query_log | OFF | OFF |
| slow_query_log_file | /var/lib/mysql/ns515408-slow.log | /var/lib/mysql/093b8c5ba5be-slow.log |
| socket | /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock |
| sort_buffer_size | 262144 | 262144 |
| sql_auto_is_null | OFF | OFF |
| sql_big_selects | ON | ON |
| sql_buffer_result | OFF | OFF |
| sql_log_bin | OFF | OFF |
| sql_log_off | OFF | OFF |
| sql_mode | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
| sql_notes | ON | ON |
| sql_quote_show_create | ON | ON |
| sql_safe_updates | OFF | OFF |
| sql_select_limit | 1.84467E+19 | 1.84467E+19 |
| sql_slave_skip_counter | 0 | 0 |
| stored_program_cache | 256 | 256 |
| super_read_only | OFF | OFF |
| sync_binlog | 1 | 1 |
| sync_frm | not_defined | not_defined |
| sync_master_info | 10000 | 10000 |
| sync_relay_log | 10000 | 10000 |
| sync_relay_log_info | 10000 | 10000 |
| system_time_zone | UTC | UTC |
| table_definition_cache | 2000 | 2000 |
| table_open_cache | 4000 | 4000 |
| table_open_cache_instances | 16 | 16 |
| thread_cache_size | 9 | 9 |
| thread_handling | one-thread-per-connection | one-thread-per-connection |
| thread_stack | 286720 | 286720 |
| time_format | not_defined | not_defined |
| time_zone | SYSTEM | SYSTEM |
| timestamp | 1620141370 | 1620235604 |
| tls_version | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| tmp_table_size | 16777216 | 16777216 |
| tmpdir | /var/tmp | /tmp |
| transaction_alloc_block_size | 8192 | 8192 |
| transaction_allow_batching | OFF | OFF |
| transaction_isolation | REPEATABLE-READ | REPEATABLE-READ |
| transaction_prealloc_size | 4096 | 4096 |
| transaction_read_only | OFF | OFF |
| transaction_write_set_extraction | XXHASH64 | XXHASH64 |
| tx_isolation | not_defined | not_defined |
| tx_read_only | not_defined | not_defined |
| unique_checks | ON | ON |
| updatable_views_with_limit | YES | YES |
| version | 8.0.21 | 8.0.22 |
| version_comment | Source distribution | MySQL Community Server - GPL |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64 | x86_64 |
| version_compile_os | Linux | Linux |
| wait_timeout | 28800 | 28800 |
| warning_count | 0 | 0 |
| activate_all_roles_on_login | OFF | OFF |
| admin_address |  |  |
| binlog_encryption | OFF | OFF |
| binlog_expire_logs_seconds | 2592000 | 2592000 |
| binlog_rotate_encryption_master_key_at_startup | OFF | OFF |
| binlog_row_event_max_size | 8192 | 8192 |
| binlog_row_metadata | MINIMAL | MINIMAL |
| binlog_row_value_options |  |  |
| binlog_transaction_compression | OFF | OFF |
| binlog_transaction_compression_level_zstd | 3 | 3 |
| caching_sha2_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys | ON | ON |
| caching_sha2_password_private_key_path | private_key.pem | private_key.pem |
| caching_sha2_password_public_key_path | public_key.pem | public_key.pem |
| create_admin_listener_thread | OFF | OFF |
| cte_max_recursion_depth | 1000 | 1000 |
| default_collation_for_utf8mb4 | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| default_table_encryption | OFF | OFF |
| generated_random_password_length | 20 | 20 |
| group_replication_consistency | EVENTUAL | EVENTUAL |
| gtid_executed |  |  |
| histogram_generation_max_mem_size | 20000000 | 20000000 |
| immediate_server_version | 999999 | 999999 |
| information_schema_stats_expiry | 86400 | 86400 |
| innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file | ON | ON |
| innodb_dedicated_server | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_directories |  |  |
| innodb_doublewrite_batch_size | 0 | 0 |
| innodb_doublewrite_dir |  |  |
| innodb_doublewrite_files | 2 | 2 |
| innodb_doublewrite_pages | 4 | 4 |
| innodb_fsync_threshold | 0 | 0 |
| innodb_idle_flush_pct | 100 | 100 |
| innodb_log_spin_cpu_abs_lwm | 80 | 80 |
| innodb_log_spin_cpu_pct_hwm | 50 | 50 |
| innodb_log_wait_for_flush_spin_hwm | 400 | 400 |
| innodb_parallel_read_threads | 4 | 4 |
| innodb_print_ddl_logs | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_redo_log_archive_dirs |  |  |
| innodb_redo_log_encrypt | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_spin_wait_pause_multiplier | 50 | 50 |
| innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir | ./#innodb_temp/ | ./#innodb_temp/ |
| innodb_undo_log_encrypt | OFF | OFF |
| innodb_validate_tablespace_paths | ON | ON |
| internal_tmp_mem_storage_engine | TempTable | TempTable |
| log_error_services | log_filter_internal; log_sink_internal | log_filter_internal; log_sink_internal |
| log_error_suppression_list |  |  |
| log_raw | OFF | OFF |
| log_slow_extra | OFF | OFF |
| mandatory_roles |  |  |
| mysqlx_bind_address | * | * |
| mysqlx_compression_algorithms | DEFLATE_STREAM,LZ4_MESSAGE,ZSTD_STREAM | DEFLATE_STREAM,LZ4_MESSAGE,ZSTD_STREAM |
| mysqlx_connect_timeout | 30 | 30 |
| mysqlx_deflate_default_compression_level | 3 | 3 |
| mysqlx_deflate_max_client_compression_level | 5 | 5 |
| mysqlx_document_id_unique_prefix | 0 | 0 |
| mysqlx_enable_hello_notice | ON | ON |
| mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout | 60 | 60 |
| mysqlx_interactive_timeout | 28800 | 28800 |
| mysqlx_lz4_default_compression_level | 2 | 2 |
| mysqlx_lz4_max_client_compression_level | 8 | 8 |
| mysqlx_max_allowed_packet | 67108864 | 67108864 |
| mysqlx_max_connections | 100 | 100 |
| mysqlx_min_worker_threads | 2 | 2 |
| mysqlx_port | 33060 | 33060 |
| mysqlx_port_open_timeout | 0 | 0 |
| mysqlx_read_timeout | 30 | 30 |
| mysqlx_socket | /var/lib/mysql/mysqlx.sock | /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock |
| mysqlx_ssl_ca |  |  |
| mysqlx_ssl_capath |  |  |
| mysqlx_ssl_cert |  |  |
| mysqlx_ssl_cipher |  |  |
| mysqlx_ssl_crl |  |  |
| mysqlx_ssl_crlpath |  |  |
| mysqlx_ssl_key |  |  |
| mysqlx_wait_timeout | 28800 | 28800 |
| mysqlx_write_timeout | 60 | 60 |
| mysqlx_zstd_default_compression_level | 3 | 3 |
| mysqlx_zstd_max_client_compression_level | 11 | 11 |
| original_commit_timestamp | 3.60288E+16 | 3.60288E+16 |
| original_server_version | 999999 | 999999 |
| partial_revokes | OFF | OFF |
| password_history | 0 | 0 |
| password_require_current | OFF | OFF |
| password_reuse_interval | 0 | 0 |
| performance_schema_error_size | 4772 | 4808 |
| performance_schema_max_digest_sample_age | 60 | 60 |
| persist_only_admin_x509_subject |  |  |
| persisted_globals_load | ON | ON |
| print_identified_with_as_hex | OFF | OFF |
| protocol_compression_algorithms | zlib,zstd,uncompressed | zlib,zstd,uncompressed |
| regexp_stack_limit | 8000000 | 8000000 |
| regexp_time_limit | 32 | 32 |
| require_row_format | OFF | OFF |
| resultset_metadata | FULL | FULL |
| rpl_read_size | 8192 | 8192 |
| schema_definition_cache | 256 | 256 |
| secondary_engine_cost_threshold | 100000 | 100000 |
| show_create_table_skip_secondary_engine | OFF | OFF |
| sql_require_primary_key | OFF | OFF |
| ssl_fips_mode | OFF | OFF |
| stored_program_definition_cache | 256 | 256 |
| table_encryption_privilege_check | OFF | OFF |
| tablespace_definition_cache | 256 | 256 |
| temptable_max_ram | 1073741824 | 1073741824 |
| temptable_use_mmap | ON | ON |
| tls_ciphersuites |  |  |
| use_secondary_engine | ON | ON |
| version_compile_zlib | 1.2.11 | 1.2.11 |
| windowing_use_high_precision | ON | ON |
| innodb_extend_and_initialize | only_in_51_8 | ON |
| innodb_log_writer_threads | only_in_51_8 | ON |
| performance_schema_show_processlist | only_in_51_8 | OFF |
| select_into_buffer_size | only_in_51_8 | 131072 |
| select_into_disk_sync | only_in_51_8 | OFF |
| select_into_disk_sync_delay | only_in_51_8 | 0 |

Comment: If you put all 1000 rows into a single `INSERT`, it will run in less than 1 second.

Comment: For analysis of `VARIABLES` and `GLOBAL STATUS`, please put them into text.  (This tabular format is hard for me to deal with.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My issue isn't this particular query. It's an example of our issue. On our mysql5.7 installation and our dockerised mysql8 installation, the same query takes less than a second. I neeed to resolve the discrepancy. In reality, the problem came up with import scripts that insert into several tables.